# Unable to Create Report in Excel or Visio when using the Visual Reports Export Function

Tags: ms-project

When I try to create a visual report exporting to Excel or Visio I get the following error message:

> An Unknown Error Has Occurred
>
> An error occurred and the requested action could not be completed at this time

I spoke to an MS Project trainer who said it could be because I didn't have PowerPivot turned on in Excel; I turned it on and it still returns the error.

When compiling the information, the error seems to occur as the progress bar gets to "building local OLAP cubes"... then it stops and the error is returned.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: [I'm not sure why this question is attracting close votes](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/software-usage-questions).

Comment: Project's visual reports feature can be "challenging". Sometimes it works great and other times it stalls out with the error message you saw. I'd try running it again, it may take a few tries. If it just won't go, it might be a compatibility issue. Please tell us what version of Project and Office you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the updated version? if not, try updating.
Errors like that are usually because of compatibility.

If the error continues, try uploading to your drive and export from there.